# Client-side polling in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, setinterval, polling

Scenario:

A mobile browser visits a site which polls the server on an interval for new data. If the user a) opens a new tab or b) switches 'apps' without exiting the browser, does the interval continue to poll in perpetuity?

Based on some initial research, it appears the answer may be 'Yes' for computer browsers but I haven't yet found anything definitive in reference to mobile. Obviously continuous polling would have serious consequences for battery life, and in my experience this hasn't been the case.

Is it necessary to use the Page Visibility API on mobile to resolve this, or is it not an issue in mobile browsers?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript timers (setTimeout, setInterval) are paused in mobile Safari. Mobile devices give the "active" applications more resource. Some support background apps, but even in such case, web events take a backseat. Switching the tab is sufficient to hang the timer.

Mobile devices should be smart enough to conserve battery. If they give the users an option to whether allow background apps, your application should behave according to the system settings. My take is to just leave it.

There're scenarios when you do want continuous polling. The solution is application specific. It usually involves time elapse detection and some sort of interpolation.